# HELP! Ubuntu 18.04 LTS freezes several times for a few seconds

Tags: 18.04, screen, freeze, lts

how are you? I have a dell i5 7th generation notebook with 8gb ram ddr4 and 1tb HDD. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the problem is that it freezes every now and then for a few seconds the screen and then returns to normal. This never happened to me with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Do you have any idea what could be happening? Any solutions?

Greetings, 
I'd be very grateful if you'd help me.